# LESS precompiler

Tags: coffeescript, less

I remember seeing something about a more simple way to write LESS, it was similar to coffeescript in its syntax. I believe it was a shorthand way to write LESS. Does anybody know what that language is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be thinking of one of the other CSS Preprocessors:

- Sass (.sass syntax) - http://sass-lang.com/
- Stylus - http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/

Comment: Yes ! Stylus is what i was thinking .. Does it work with a LESS file?

Comment: Stylus has its own syntax for defining things like variables and mixins, in addition to not allowing punctuation like curly braces and semi-colons.  You would have to port your LESS files into something Stylus can understand.  Other than that, everything LESS can do, Stylus can do too.

Comment: I should also note that it is probably easier to migrate a LESS file to Sass (.scss syntax) than it would be to migrate to Stylus.  Once the migration is made, you're free to use both scss and sass syntax in the same project, provided you don't mix the syntax in the same file.